# plugin nao funcionando, routes e jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou usando este plugin para explorar routes com jQuery sem precisar migrar para o AngularJS. Porem nao estou recebendo a resposta na caixa de log, que era pra retornar com o seguinte código

```
$.router.add(/items/:item", "foo", function(data) {
console.log(data.item);
});
```

Qual ponto eu estou errando em especifico?

http://jsfiddle.net/kbsa5269/2/

No jsfiddle contem o link do plugin e uma demonstração, que nao esta a funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Acho que temos um erro de sintaxe.

```
$.router.add("/items/:item", "foo", function(data) {
  console.log(data.item);
 });
```